# redirecting folder to a php file

Tags: php, localhost

I have a folder containing PHP files. When I open those file through localhost, I get the list of all the files inside that folder. Instead I want a specific PHP file to be opened when I click on that folder through localhost. How do I do that?

Comment: add index.php in your folder. or rename a file with index.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a file named `index.php` inside your folder and code inside that.

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
echo "I will be opened first";
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you start a folder in FTP mode, it will automatically make a PHP file named index.PHP. I would recommend using a different FTP program if this occurs again.